# Tile View Android File Browser

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have created a file browser using this code:

http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/browse_files

I would like to create a tile view like this grid:

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/grid_view

I assume I need to change the code that displays the rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/file_picker_image"
    android:layout_width="40dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:src="@drawable/file"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_picker_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="filename"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to change it to a GridView, however, I receive an error that it's not supported:

**Java.Lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView**

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out. I checked in the code here:

https://github.com/jmawebtech/MonoDroidGridViewFragment